# Can you use a different bootloader rather than GRUB?

Tags: grub2, 16.04

Title says all.

I'm trying to see if another alternative to GRUB is working.

If you can do it, what are the steps?

If you can't do it, why?

Comment: Lilo still boots up my Slackware system without fail and should boot Ubuntu with a little fiddling :)

Comment: An alternative similar to GRUB is BURG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this post http://www.linux.org/threads/linux-bootloaders.4489/ there are:

- LILO
- ELILO
- GNU GRUB
- SYSLINUX / EXTLINUX
- PXELINUX
- SILO
- PALO
- Yaboot
- Das U-Boot
- Barebox
- BURG

Most of them should (should!) work on any distribution, including ubuntu, but not all of them support for example UEFI-Systems. I'd suppose you'd set up an ubuntu in a virtual environment (for example VirtualBox) and experiment there with which works where.

---

To install, I describe here the processes of the most common bootloaders. All others can be found online easily and would go beyond the scope of this answer.

**Installing LILO**

Installing LILO is very straightforward.

- First, you install the package from apt: `sudo apt-get install lilo`
- After that, you can install the bootloader by typing `lilo` in a root-shell.

Detailed instructions: https://wiki.debian.org/LILO

**Installing GRUB**

Usually, GRUB is installed by default. If you are however on a running system with another bootloader, you can install GRUB like this:

- Install the package (if not yet installed): `sudo apt-get install grub2`
- Use the command `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` (where sdX is your system partition, for example `/dev/sda`)

Detailed instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

**Installing EXTLINUX**

- Install the needed packages: `sudo apt-get install extlinux syslinux-common`
- Install the bootloader: `sudo extlinux --install /boot/extlinux`
- To display a menu, if needed, there are a few additional steps. The exact steps would be too much for this answer, but you can find it in the detailes instructions.

Detailed instructions: http://shallowsky.com/linux/extlinux.html

And, important, if something doesn't work correctly, follow the BootRepair-Steps here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Is this answer only copied from a link?

Comment: No. Only the list of the bootloaders (which answers your question) is from the link.
If you don't want an easy answer, don't ask a question you could also type in google and get the same results.

Comment: "If you can do it, what are the steps?" That does not adress my question.

Comment: Well, that's a very broad question. Every loader is diffrent. Which one or which ones shall I include in my answer?

Comment: Please edit your question, and put a link to the install instructions.

Comment: I updated my answer with the most common loaders.